# Infinite Login Loop?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, authentication

I'm experiencing a problem with my login system in my app.

When the app first opens, FVC is the main view controller. FVC then checks if I am logged in/if my session key is still valid, and if not, then it makes the LoginViewController pop up over my entire screen, forcing me to login to continue. Once I login with my right username and password, it checks quickly with a JSON file on the web and if it returns no error, it returns a session key. The problem is, I know it is correctly getting the JSON file and parsing it as I did some tests with NSLog but as soon as I login with the correct info, it dismisses the loginView and for half a second, shows the main view, then the loginView pops right back up! Something isn't right and I hope you can find the problem with my code. Michael.

First view controller:

```
 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
//Put login check here.
LoginViewController *login = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"login"];

[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

// create the URL we'd like to query

[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];

myURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"https://URL/v1/?get&action=getservers&session_key=", login.sessionKey]];

// we'll receive raw data so we'll create an NSData Object with it
NSData *myData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:myURL];

// now we'll parse our data using NSJSONSerialization
id myJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

// typecast an array and list its contents
NSDictionary *jsonArray = (NSDictionary *)myJSON;

NSLog(@"%@",[jsonArray objectForKey:@"status"]);

if ([[jsonArray objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"ERROR"]) {

    [self presentViewController:login animated:NO completion:nil];
}


[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

}
```

Login view controller:

```
- (IBAction)loginAction:(id)sender {
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

// create the URL we'd like to query
NSURL *myURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@", @"https://URL/v1/?get&action=login&username=", usernameField.text, @"&password=", passwordField.text]];

// we'll receive raw data so we'll create an NSData Object with it
NSData *myData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:myURL];

// now we'll parse our data using NSJSONSerialization
id myJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

// typecast an array and list its contents
//NSArray *jsonArray = (NSArray *)myJSON;
NSDictionary *jsonArray = (NSDictionary *)myJSON;

NSLog(@"%@",[jsonArray objectForKey:@"status"]);

if ([[jsonArray objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"OK"]) {
    FirstViewController *dashView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"dashView"];

    sessionKey = [jsonArray objectForKey:@"new_session_key"];
    NSLog(@"%@",sessionKey);

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
} else {

}

[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

}
```

Comment: After you login and you see the FVC what do does nslog shows NSLog(@"%@",[jsonArray objectForKey:@"status"])

Comment: @Yan , It shows: "2013-08-08 16:49:04.297 AHMC[3690:907] OK
2013-08-08 16:49:04.298 AHMC[3690:907] b891945bb5344180a2ef25db07c770"

Comment: I doubt that is the problem but i don't see [super viewDidAppear:animated]

Comment: Set a breakpoint at [self presentViewController:login animated:NO completion:nil]; and see if it's getting called after you login

Comment: @Yan , where should I put that?

Comment: Ok I'll try that now.

Comment: [super viewDidAppear:animated]; should go in the beginning of the viewDidAppear method

Comment: I put the [super viewDidAppear:animated]; at the beginning of the viewDidAppear method and also a breakpoint on the suggested line. This is the output: "2013-08-08 16:57:24.687 AHMC[424:60b] OK
2013-08-08 16:57:24.688 AHMC[424:60b] 17fc84f45a68bcb715f42673106496". Also, now the view doesn't even disappear anymore to reappear, weird.

Comment: Did it stop at  [self presentViewController:login animated:NO completion:nil]; ?  You have to press continue execution on the bottom where debugger is to proceed.  It will call it once but the question is why it is calling it the second time.

Comment: No it didn't stop then I guess, no breakpoint continue button was shown. I put it at that line, should I put it before by 1 line?

Comment: Even one line before it's not working.

Comment: Did it show the login view controller the first time?  When you put the break point on [self presentViewController:login animated:NO completion:nil];  try to put the break point on if and see if it's going inside the if statement

Comment: I put the break on it and yet it ignored it as it did show loginViewController the first time without me pressing any button to continue.

Comment: What if you put the breakpoint on the if statement?  What happens then?

Comment: Still as if it wasn't there, the compiler ignores it when running the app.

Comment: Are you showing login controller anywhere else in the code? i don't think it's calling it there.

Comment: Managed to get it to 'disappear' but then it reappears. Putting a breakpoint on the suggested statement shows me that is IS being called TWO times, once when the app launches, and then after I successfully log in.

Comment: I think for some reason it is using the old URL or something, as right before it runs that code for a second time, it shows ERROR in the console from NSLog.

Comment: So it is going into the if statement twice?  What is the nslog showing the second time around

Comment: It is showing ERROR, as if it's using the old link or something.

Comment: That's the issue then.  You should probably store the login information in some global variable or nsuserdefaults so you don't have to call the webservice everytime this view appears.  Depends i guess on your program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the `login.sessionKey`.  Do NSLog on it.  It is probably nil.  I don't see where you are setting it.  That's probably you get an error from your webservice.  Check it out.